# Access private member of nested friend class in specialized template

Tags: c++, nested, friend

The following code fails to compile in Visual studio 2103 Express preview:

```
template<int N> class TTOuter;

template<>
class TTOuter<1>
{
public:
    class inner
    {
        friend class TTOuter<1>;

    private:
        inner(int n) : data(n) {;}
        int data;
    };

private:
    inner x;

public:
    TTOuter(int n) : x(n) {;} //Fails here
};
```

Error: "TTOuter<1>::inner::inner(int n)" is inaccessible

An analogous access succeeds if the outer class is not a specialized template:

```
class Outer
{
public:
    class inner
    {
        friend class Outer;

    private:
        inner(int n) : data(n) { ; }
        int data;
    };

private:
    inner x;

public:
    Outer(int n) : x(n) { ; }
};
```

Gives no error.

I tried forward declaring TTOuter<1> like:

```
template<> class TTOuter<1>;
```

I also tried replacing the friend declaration by:

```
template<int N> friend class TTOuter;
```

But neither works.

Would appreciate any insight.
Thank You.

Comment: It compiles fine with VS2012: http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/3R . Please show a code that _does_ cause the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is nothing more than a typo in your code

```
public:
    TOuter(int n) : x(n) {;} //Fails here
  //^^^^^^ Shouldn't it be TTouter???
};
```

Edited:

If I edit a bit your code:

```
class TTOuter<1>
{
public:
    typedef TTOuter this_type; // <-- I add this typedef
    class inner
    {
        friend class this_type; // <-- Intellisense works
        //friend class TTOuter<1>; // <-- intellisense barks
        inner(int n) : data(n) { ; }
        int data;
    };
    TTOuter(int n) : x(0) {}
};
```

Now intellisense stops complaining.

Comment: I see in your code you have edited the constructor and replaced TOuter with TTOuter. That compiles fine in VS2013 preview

Comment: The code in my editor has TTOuter. Had just copied it wrongly. I'm pasting the code exactly as in the editor, but oddly, in my case, it is not getting past intellisense.

Comment: @skm It compiles just fine. Intellisense has nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: I see. Looks like a bug in intellisense.

Comment: Oh, I see. I tried compiling a test.cpp woth TTOuter<1> X(5), and there is no problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. BTW and off-topic, do you happen to know when the final version of VS 2013 is due?

Comment: Interesting - meaning I have no clue. I didn't even know that
    "typedef TTOuter this_type"
could be a valid typedef. Oddly enough, if I replace it with
    "typedef TTOuter<1> this_type"
the errors still remain. Certainly looks like a bug in intellisense.

Comment: @Juan, Thanks for your experiment. The VS 2013 can be misleading, since even a minor syntax error in the code will make it output all the (possibly unrelated and possibly _wrong_) intellisense errors.